# How to smooth scroll to div whithout anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to smooth scroll to div whithout anchors?

My html:

```js
$("#click1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section1").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    });


$("#click2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    });
    
$("#click3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section3").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
.menu {
 position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #00a3e0;
}

.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#section1 {
  height:300px;
  background:yellow;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:40px;
}

#section2 {
  height:500px;
  background:green;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:40px;
}

#section3 {
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<a id="click1">click1</a>
<a id="click2">click2</a>
<a id="click3">click3</a>
</div>


<div id="section1">I'm Sectoin1</div>
<div id="section2">I'm Sectoin2</div>
<div id="section3">I'm Sectoin3</div>
```

I want to click "click3" scroll to `<div id="section3"></div>` and click "click1" scroll to `<div id="section1"></div>`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'without anchors'? The important part of the code is the `id`, so you can use any element type you like so long as it has the right `id` on it

Comment: Then swap the anchor elements for something else... Example: span tags https://jsfiddle.net/b6sc1sff/ You can also cut back on the source code by editing your selectors and a few other changes https://jsfiddle.net/vsh0nns0/

Comment: To be fair, if you kept them as anchors and added a href, you could make it more accessible and cut down on your jquery code: https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/03bkkj41/1/

Comment: @Pete you wouldn't even need to add a `href`, since they relate via the increment you can replace `click` with `section`. Working example in my comment above, but I do like your take on it.

Comment: @NewToJS my fiddle is more about accessibility - links that work when js is turned off, and I would rather use a data attribute than do a replace on the fly like that

Comment: @Pete Ah yes! Very good, I didn't think of that what so ever. Your take will be much better and I will be sure to keep something like that in mind for future :)

Comment: Thanks every one. It's very good ans.